# dash to dock is not showing what it's supposed to

Tags: 20.04, unity-dash

I'm new to Ubuntu. I tried to install some themes and followed some tutorials. after installing dash to dock and applying some themes, when i change the position of dock from left to bottom the dock's body is connected to bottom of the screen. (It's not the case when i change its position to left.
Any help is appreciated
[image]
[image]

Comment: What themes it may make a difference?

Comment: *"dock's body is connected to bottom of the screen"* isn't that what you asked it to do?

Comment: Correct me if I am misunderstanding the question - you want the dock to be at the bottom of the screen but instead of "attached" like the photo, you want it to be floating. Similar to MacOS? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm positioning the dock to left and it's fixed, but not when i'm moving it to bottom. Yes I want it to look floating like macos. I also added the image of left positioning @fralewhale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Install this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3730/floating-dock/